# Get collection result from string located in array

Tags: laravel, collections

To avoid multiples rows in my form, i attempt to get a collection result with key located in a raay but it doesn't work. Is this possible ? How ?

```
$days = [
'lundi' => (object)[
    'status' => 'lundiStatus',
    'open' => 'lundiOpen',
    'close' => 'lundiClose'
],
'mardi' => (object)[
    'status' => 'mardiStatus',
    'open' => 'mardiOpen',
    'close' => 'mardiClose'
];

@foreach($days as $day => $data)
   <?php dd($collection->$data->status); ?>
@endforeach
```

I get 500 error : Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string ...

Any idea ?

Comment: Your key is `$day`, not `$data`.

Comment: What is `$collection`? Is `$days` an array or a `Collection`? Too many unknowns with your code. But, `$day` is going to be `lundi` or `mardi`, and `$data` will be the `object`, do `dd($data->status)` should show you `lundiStatus` (dies after the 1st loop)

Comment: Hi Raphael, I think you should share more of your code, as we cannot know if `$collection` is an actual Collection(type) or not with the information you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$collection` is an `array` or a `Collection` like:

```
$collection = [
    "lundiStatus" => "foo",
    "mardiStatus" => "foo"
];
```

or

```
$collection = new Collection([
    "lundiStatus" => "foo",
    "mardiStatus" => "foo"
]);
```

you can access by this way:

```
@foreach($days as $day => $data)
   <?php dd($collection[$data->status]); ?>
@endforeach
```

But if `$collection` is an `object` like:

```
$collection = (object) array(
    "lundiStatus" => "foo",
    "mardiStatus" => "foo"
);
```

you can access by this way:

```
@foreach($days as $day => $data)
   <?php dd($collection->{$data->status}); ?>
@endforeach
```

See the **braces** for access property value of an object in a statement.